# Java Timer Code

Tags: java, timer

so I have this code which counts up to 21, but I wanna make a 3 second timer for each number like this:
1
3 seconds later
2
3 seconds later
3
3 seconds later
4
Like that, here is my code, if you got any ideas, can you please help me and do something with it?

```
package me.Capz.While;

public class WhileLoop {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double money = 0;

        while (money < 22) {

            System.out.println(money);

            money++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `Thread.sleep(3000)` in the loop body (and add `throws` or `try`/`catch` as appropriate).

Comment: You do not begin with 1 as you stated in your description. Use money++ before the println to print 1 as first output.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this is to use [`Thread#sleep(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

```
package me.Capz.While;

public class WhileLoop {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double money = 0;

        while (money < 22) {
            System.out.println(money);
            money++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000L); // The number of milliseconds to sleep for
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Some exception handling code here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an asynchronous, nonblocking solution of your problem statement :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAndSchedule(1);
}

public static void printAndSchedule(final int money) {
    if (money < 22) {
        System.out.println(money);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                printAndSchedule(money + 1);
            }
        }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User below code.This will pause for a 3 seconds.

```
System.out.println(money);
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    double money = 0;
    while (money < 22) {
        System.out.println(money);
        money++;
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```